# how can I get an item in the specific table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and I want to get the image source in the third row using jquery.

```
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Avatar</th>
  </tr>      
 <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>29</td>
     <td><img src="json.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Victoria</td>
    <td>Cooper</td>
    <td>38</td>
     <td><img src="cooper.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways, but `$('#someTableId').find('tr').eq(2)` would work.

[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

#### NOTE

- in your headder row, your HTML is malformed, you have the row as `th` with `td`s inside them, that should still be a `tr` element with `th` elements inside it, see the fixes in the example below
- The below adds an ID to the table in order to target only that table's rows, adjust as needed

Here's a simple example

```js
$('#someTableId').find('tr').eq(2).addClass('test');
```

```css
.test td {
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="someTableId"> 
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Avatar</th>
  </tr>     
 <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>29</td>
     <td><img src="json.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Victoria</td>
    <td>Cooper</td>
    <td>38</td>
     <td><img src="cooper.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the n-th element by **:eq()**

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

For your case :

```
$("td:eq(2) > img").attr('src');
```

Comment: Careful with this approach, `$("td:eq(2) > img")`  will target the image tags in the 3rd column of *all* rows in *all* tables on the page

Answer (score 1):

you can use css pseudo selector `nth-child()`

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their
>   position in a group of siblings

You can read more here [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

.

```js
console.log($('#tableID tr:nth-child(3) img').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
 <tr>
  <th>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Avatar</td>
  </th> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>29</td>
     <td><img src="json.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Victoria</td>
    <td>Cooper</td>
    <td>38</td>
     <td><img src="cooper.gif"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Careful with this approach, `$('tr:nth-child(3) img')` will target the 3rd row of *all* tables on the page

Comment: @DelightedD0D I've fixed the answer so it will target the specific table